# Send HTML Element Text From View To Controller

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I call to a function on the controller from a view like this : (when the user press the button)

```
  <input id="deactive_btn" type="button" value="Deactive" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SetActive", "Home", new { email = ??? ,activeStatus = ???  })'"/>
```

The purpse of this button is:

I have a list of user that display to the admin, the admin is allow to deactivate user(the admin can achive it by pressing the button "Deactivate")

Now i need to send to the "SetActive" function in the controller the email of the user so we can look him up and deactivate the user, the email of the user is display in a TD in the table of users, i gave it ID how can i get the value from it(from the html element) and place it here:

```
@Url.Action("SetActive", "Home", new { email = HERE!
```

This is my complete code of the list user :

```
foreach (AppUser appUser in userList)
{
    <tr>
        <td width="15%">@appUser.name</td>
        <td class="text-left" width="15%">@appUser.date.Substring(0, appUser.date.IndexOf(" "))</td>
        <td class="text-left" width="10%">@appUser.role</td>
        <td id="user_email" class="text-left" width="24%">@appUser.email</td>
        <td class="text-left" width="10%"><span id=@Url.Content("status_lbl" + index) class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
        <td class="btn-group-sm text-center">
            <input id="@Url.Content("freeze_btn" + index)" type="button" value="Deactivate" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SetActive", "Home", new { email =  ,activeStatus = Html  })' "  />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default " />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default " />
        </td>
    </tr>
    index++;
}
```

**And this is My Jquery script :**

```
$('input[id^=freeze_btn]').click(function (event) {
    var btn = $(event.target);
    var text = $(this).attr('value');
    var newid = $(this).attr('id').replace('freeze_btn', 'status_lbl');
    if (text == "Active") {
        btn.val("Deactivate");
        $('#' + newid).removeClass("label-danger").addClass("label-success").text("Active");
    }
    if (text == "Deactivate") {
        btn.val("Active");
        $('#' + newid).removeClass("label-success").addClass("label-danger").text("Unactive");
    }
});
```

I think I can do it using a form but there is any other way?

There is motivation for ajax form over html form?

Comment: You're going to need to learn Javascript, or give each row its own Deactivate button.

Comment: i have gave each row button and i'm allso using jquery(its my weak side but..).

I edit my post for the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Since each row has its own button, you're fine. You can use Razor to set the value in your HTML attributes:

```
<input onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SetActive", "Home", 
    new { email = appUser.Email.ID ,activeStatus = Html  })' "  />
```

I've removed some of the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: The problem is the other parameter i need to send to function and its the text(value) of the button itself because when its active i need to put 1 in the database and when its deactivate i need to put 0 in the database(you can see the j query section if you wont find it hard to understand).
so how can i pass the parameter 'activeStatus' that represent the value of the button ?

Comment: So you just want your `activeStatus` parameter to be `"Deactivate"` in that button? You could just hard code it, unless I'm missing something. A simpler (and smaller HTML payload) way to do it would be to use custom `data-` attributes on your `<input>` elements and in your click event redirect to that page manually.